# Splitting up lines in a paragraph of a text file using Mac Terminal

Tags: command-line, microsoft-word, terminal

I have the following:

```
sanskrit verse ॥ २॥meaning word-wise of sanskrit।hindi verse।
```

Desired output with 1 line gap:

```
sanskrit verse ॥ २॥

meaning word-wise of sanskrit।

hindi verse।
```

I have a Mac. Windows CMD clue at https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html.

11000 pages of following data to be split. Post splitting, the above 3 parts of sanskrit-wordwiseMeaning-hindi need to (merged) as "text" for json while retaining 1 line gap as done above in (split).  Real sample:

धर्म: प्रोज्मितकैतवोत्र परमो निर्मत्सराणां सतांवेद्यं वास्तवमत्र वस्तु शिवदं तापत्रयोन्मूलनम्‌ ।श्रीमद्धागवते महामुनिकृते कि वा परैरी श्र:सद्यो हृद्यवरुध्यतेउत्र कृतिभि: शुश्रूषुभिस्तत्क्षणात्‌ ॥ २॥धर्म:--धार्मिकता; प्रोज्झित--पूर्ण रूप से अस्वीकृत; कैतव:--सकाम विचार से प्रच्छन्न; अत्र--यहाँ; परम:--सर्वोच्च;निर्मत्सराणाम्‌--शतप्रतिशत शुद्ध हृदय वालों के; सताम्‌-भक्तों को; वेद्यम्--जानने योग्य; वास्तवम्‌--वास्तविक;अतन्र--यहाँ; वस्तु--वस्तु, चीज; शिवदम्‌--कल्याण; ताप-त्रय--तीन प्रकार के कष्ट; उन्मूलनम्‌--समूल नष्ट करना;श्रीमतू--सुन्दर; भागवते-- भागवत पुराण में; महा-मुनि--महामुनि ( व्यासदेव ) द्वारा; कृते--संग्रह किया गया, रचनाकी गई; किम्‌--क्या है; वा--आवश्यकता; परैः--अन्य; ईश्वर: --परमे श्वर; सद्य: -- तुरन्त; हृदि--हृदय में;अवरूुध्यते--हृढ़ हो गया; अत्र--यहाँ; कृतिभि:--पवित्र व्यक्तियों द्वारा; शुश्रूषुभि:--संस्कार द्वारा; ततू-क्षणात्‌--अविलम्ब।यह भागवत पुराण, भौतिक कारणों से प्रेरित होने वाले समस्त धार्मिक कृत्यों को पूर्णरूप से बहिष्कृत करते हुए, सर्वोच्च सत्य का प्रतिपादन करता है, जो पूर्ण रूप से शुद्धहृदय वाले भक्तों के लिए बोधगम्य है। यह सर्वोच्च सत्य वास्तविकता है जो माया से पृथक्‌होते हुए सबों के कल्याण के लिए है। ऐसा सत्य तीनों प्रकार के संतापों को समूल नष्टकरने वाला है। महामुनि व्यासदेव द्वारा ( अपनी परिपक्वावस्था में ) संकलित यहसौंदर्यपूर्ण भागवत ईश्वर-साक्षात्कार के लिए अपने आप में पर्याप्त है। तो फिर अन्य किसीशास्त्र की क्या आवश्यकता है? जैसे जैसे कोई ध्यानपूर्वक तथा विनीत भाव से भागवत केसन्देश को सुनता है, वैसे वैसे ज्ञान के इस संस्कार ( अनुशीलन ) से उसके हृदय में परमेश्वरस्थापित हो जाते हैं।

Comment: Possible delimiters - delimiter ॥ for sanskrit to meaning and । for meaning to hindi verse and 3rd delimiter-condition of । for hindi to next sanskrit verse.  Right now data is in Ms word replace ^p to blank format i.e. having no gaps at all !  Any set of commands for mac terminal would be appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify these details. I don't see these delimiters in your sample. This is probably trivial in Awk but without clarifications it's hard to suggest anything.

Comment: Check ॥ after २. Check । which is eqv. to full stop of english in hindi script.

Comment: So is all the data on a single line?

Comment: yes. there were gaps, empty rows but i did ^p to blank in ms word find replace.

Comment: `sed 's/\(२॥\|।\)/\
/g'` with a literal newline before `/g` seems to do what you are asking. Demo: https://ideone.com/tZkQPf

Comment: For what it's worth, the Windows link is pretty useless. I don't think you'd use a `for` loop in Windows, either. Certainly not in shell script; https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: Thanks. But i need 1 line gap after each delimiter since it would be read on small mobile screen/apk thereby to avoid clutter.  Secondly, please tell me script to copy paste in terminal as there are 335 such text files.

Comment: Then put two newlines. See my answer just now. Me, I prefer compact *especially* on a small screen.

Answer (score 0):

Having all your text on a single line is a rather messy complication, but what you are asking should be simple enough.

```
sed 's/\(२॥\|।\)/\
\
/g' filename
```

will split the text onto separate lines on either of the two separators you specified, with an empty line between.

Perhaps a better approach going forward is to split on every `।` before a `२॥` and then take it from there.

```
sed 's/।\([^।]*२॥\)/\
\1/g' filename
```

... and maybe even then replace the final delimiter so you have the same delimiter throughout, because then you can pipe that to Awk and split into individual fields and go straight to JSON.

```
sed 's/।\([^।]*\)/\
\1।/g' filename |
awk -F '।' 'BEGIN { print "[" }
    { if (s) print ","
      printf "{ \"verse\": \"%s\", \"meaning\": \"%s\", \"translation\": \"%s\"}", $1, $2, $3
      s=1; }
END { print "]" }'
```

To loop over a large number of files, either `sed` them all in one go:

```
sed 's/।\([^।]*\)/\
\1।/g' * | awk ...
```

or loop over them:

```
for file in *; do
    sed '...' "$file" | awk ...
done
```

Comment: The sample you show doesn't really produce useful output, but also because I can't read Devanagari, I can't tell if it's almost correct or completely wrong. I hope this can at least help you ask a better question.

Comment: Thanks. It's almost correct. But 2 ques. - need to add a blank line after each delimiter what is the code for that and what is the piping code after awk...JSON has only 1 field called "text" :-  { "text" : "...combo of sanskrit-meaning-hindi..." },

Comment: That's a pretty useless JSON format. You should split up the data into as small components as you can.

Comment: To print a newline in Awk, add `\n` in the string. The first code snippet shows how to do the same in `sed`.

Comment: There is no piping done after the Awk script. Not sure what you are trying to ask.

Comment: There was an extra backslash, sorry about that, fixed now.